# How to get Camera FocalLenght to enter ActionsEditor?

Tags: animation, dopesheet, actions

When you select an object, as you put some keyframes for location, rotation and so on, you get an action associated to them but **if you select the camera and keyframe the focal length, you don't get an action.**

The workaround I used is to add a CustomProperty to the object "Camera" and use it as a driver for the focal length. Keyframing the CustomProperty you get an action that you can use to animate focal length.

Did anyone figure out how to get an action from FocalLength animation?